# Android 4.4 Service Bluetooth does not exist

Tags: android, shell, service, bluetooth, terminal

I tried to toggle Bluetooth from Terminal with the following command as root:

```
'service call bluetooth 3' for enable

'service call bluetooth 4' for disable
```

But I get the error
`service: service bluetooth does not exist`

I searched for bluetooth in the server list and there's only `bluetooth_manager`

I have a rooted Nexus 5 (Android 4.4).

Is there any other way to toggle Bluetooth via Terminal?

Maybe with 'am start com.android.settings....' ?

What I want to do is enabling Wifi and disable Bluetooth at the same time and reverse.
For Wifi there's no problem with `svc wifi enable/disable`

Comment: Fixed it using Python. (toggleBluetoothState())

Answer (score 2):

As *root* using service call:

`adb shell su -c service call bluetooth_manager 6` turn bluetooth on

`adb shell su -c service call bluetooth_manager 8` turn bluetooth off

Details of `bluetooth_manager` in [android.bluetooth.IBluetoothManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/bluetooth/IBluetoothManager.java/).

Or as *non-root* using keyevents:

`adb shell am start -a android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS`

`adb shell input keyevent 19`

`adb shell input keyevent 23`